# Condensate pipe touching basement floor ok?

Tags: pipe, condensation

I recently replaced my leaking condensate pipe that was crusty and rusted. I've replaced it with a 1" copper pipe in the same position the old galvanized pipe was. Please see the picture I've attached.

My question and concern that I have is that, the previous pipe that was on the floor of the basement was extrememly rusted. Much more than the vertical standing pipes made from the same material. Since I put the pipe in the same place, near the ground of the basement, would the pipe corrode faster from being so close to the basement floor?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image: Furnace]

Comment: What's the make and model of the boiler?

Comment: The third picture shows the pipe conneceted to the furnace and I attached a picture of the furnace as well. I was reading online about furnaces since I wanted to figure out what type mine was. Does the fourth picture show if my furnace is a two pipe steam furnace or single pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the floor was the downfall of the old pipe, the copper will do much better. While everything looks dry, the floor & bottom of the wall concrete is moist from microscopic condensation, since they're always colder than the air.

Starting the condensate pipe as high as possible will minimize pipe problems & more importantly draining problems. You want the pipe pitched downward for as far as possible to the sump.

Preferably the pipe should never be flat or level & it should have a close by trap, like under your sink. The pipe should also have a clean-out, this is actually a bleach pour-in. Condensate is quite nasty & stinks if the pipe's not bleached once a year or as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that ansswered my question. Unfortunately the pipe is already laid down with about a .5" clearance off the ground. Thats better than before, as the old galvinized pipe was embedded into the floor. Would insulation help in my situation or would it be advisable to redo it since i already took down the wall?

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd say no on the insulation for as-is, that'll make the pipe flatter. But, if you can re-do it to legal & proper, then by all means do that. You'd just slip on pipe insulation at the end that contacts the floor.

Comment: isn't PVC not suitable for hot water? The water that flows through the pipe is very hot.

Comment: Yeah, PVC is only good for 140° maximum. Up to & after that it can sag badly & joints can fall apart. Stick with the copper.

Comment: I am sorry but you can not use pvc piping on a steam return system. the condensate will not corrode copper tubing. Did you follow the same path as the old piping and is it the same size as the old piping. As for replacing steam returns you only replace them if they are leaking not if they are rusted on the outside. Someone talked about bleaching the condensate; what the heck is that??? Never heard of that. From the pictures you can not tell if the system is 1 or 2 pipe system. If the rads have 1 pipe entering and a vent it is a 1 pipe system. If a pipe in and another out it is a 2 pipe system.

Comment: Bleaching is just pouring bleach through the line. The condensate water can get very nasty in just a few months and develop a skin that blocks flow. It's really more for forced air systems, especially if the condensate is pumped. But, any condensate type of appliance is prone to it eventually. Your service technician will take care of it infrequently with a boiler.

Comment: I am sorry Iggy,  but you must not have any experience with steam systems. Bleaching is never used in steam return lines or anywhere in a steam system. The condensate water does not get nasty. The condensate in steam systems is not the same condensate you get from a 90+ natural gas furnace. Also return lines are never insulated unless it is to cut down on over heating an area where the lines are. People that come here are looking for real answers.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the correction. But, that's why I said in-frequently. I haven't had a natural gas boiler, but the oils I've had did get sooty-slimy build-up...maybe every 5-years. The bleaching is just the condensate line, nothing to do with the system's loop at all. The insulation was just for the very end of the copper condensate drain line, where it touched the floor...just to avoid corrosion at that spot.